# How to compare a point with polyline

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have an array where my all polylines are stored.

```
var polyArrayCollection = [polyline1, polyline2, polyline3]
```

Now when I click on map I get LatLng values of that point.

Now I want to compare that point LatLng value with points which are in each polyline.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the points in a polyline using `getLatLngs` method of the polyline. Next, you can loop the resulting array and compare it elements with your `LatLng`. Something like this :

```
for (var pl in polyArrayCollection){
    var pts = polyArrayCollection[pl].getLatLngs();
    for (var pt in pts){
        //compare it with your LatLng, assuming it is stored in myPt variable
        if (pts[pt].equals(myPt)){
            //do something if the points are equal
        }
    }
}
```